# For how many numbers $1\le k\le n$ does there exist $a$, $b\in\Bbb Z$, so that $k=a^2+b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

> For how many numbers $1\le k\le n$ does there exist $a$, $b\in\Bbb Z$, so that $k=a^2+b^2$? Give an approximation, focus more on the lower bound.

Let the number be $f(n)$. First, I know the following.

> Let $k=p_1p_2\cdots p_tM^2$, where $p_i$ are prime($1\le i\le t$), and $M\in\Bbb N$.
>
> $\exists~a$, $b\in\Bbb Z$, so that $n=a^2+b^2$ $\iff$ $\forall~1\le i\le t$, $p_i\not\equiv3\pmod4$.

So I tried to do
\[f(n)\ge n-\sum_{\text{prime }p\le n}\sum_{i}\frac{n(-1)^{i+1}}{p^i}=n-\sum_{\text{prime }p\le n}\frac1{1+p}.\]
But it doesn't work. However, the $f(n)$ seems quite large.

Comment: This is the Gauss circle problem, with a sum provided on [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html). Just replace $r^2$ with $n$. You may also want to look at [3b1b's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY) for an exposition.

Comment: @Kyky Thanks. I'll have a look.

Comment: One more thing, would you consider $a^2+b^2$ distinct from $b^2+a^2$, and do you want to allow positive $a, b$ only? You would get slightly different answers in both cases.

Comment: @Kyky I notice something more. If $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, and the ordered pair $(a,b)\ne(c,d)$, I don't want double count. So I think the linked is a bit different problem.

Comment: OK, so just to be clear you want to count the number of $k$ with such a representation?

Comment: @Kyky $\text{}$Yes.

Comment: @youtdoo $p_i$ can be $2$ also

Comment: Turns out that this is (relatively) well-known - Ramanujan apparently [proved that there are $O\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}\right)$ such numbers below n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant?useskin=vector#cite_note-mw-3), and the proportionality constant is [about $0.764$](https://oeis.org/A064533).

Comment: $418$ seems wrong. $a^2$ is always $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, $b^2$ also, so $a^2+b^2$ is always $0$,$1$ or $2$ modulo $4$.  So we are sure that maximum 75% of integers between $0$ and $n$ can be written as $a^2+b^2$

Comment: @Lourrran Perhaps the code is wrong. I'm new to Maple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a heuristic justifying why $f(m)\sim\frac{m}{\sqrt{\ln m}}$:

We know that $n$ is representable iff it is divisible by $r^{2k}$ but not $r^{2k+1}$ for all primes of the form $r\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Now for a given $r$, the proportion of numbers not divisible by $r$ is $1-\frac{1}{r}$, but we then want to include those divisible by $r^2$ so we multiply by $\sim1+\frac{1}{r^2}$, but then we don't want to include those divisible by $r^3$ so we multiply by $\sim1+\frac{1}{r^3}$, and so on and so forth.

Now consider all such $r$. This gives us

$$f(m)\sim m\prod_{r\leq \sqrt m}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\prod_{r^2\leq \sqrt m}\left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\prod_{r^3\leq \sqrt m}\left(1-\frac{1}{r^3}\right)\cdots$$

By binomial expansion, the terms past $1-\frac{1}{r}$ converge to a finite number, so we ignore them. Hence,

$$f(m)\sim m\prod_{r\leq \sqrt m}1-\frac{1}{r}$$

By Dirichlet's Theorem, about half of all primes are $3\pmod 4$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\ln\prod_{r\leq\sqrt m}1-\frac{1}{r}&=\sum_{r\leq\sqrt m}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\\
&\approx\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p\leq\sqrt m}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\prod_{p\leq\sqrt m}1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\\
&\approx-\frac{1}{2}\ln\sum^m_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}\\
&\approx-\frac{1}{2}\ln\ln m=\ln\left(\sqrt{\ln m}\right)^{-1}\\
\end{align*}

Or in other words,

$$f(m)\sim \frac{m}{\sqrt{\ln m}}$$

Proving that the proportionality constant is equal to $\lambda=\left(\frac{1}{2}\prod\frac{1}{1-r^{-2}}\right)^{\frac12}$ is rather tricky (and will need analytic number theory knowledge). The proof is a bit too complicated for here, but you can read "Topics in Number Theory Vol. II" by William J. Leveque for more details.

You may also be interested in [this article, which uses zeta functions to quickly find $\lambda$](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/landau.ps), or [higher order approximations for $f(m)$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-085/S0025-5718-1964-0159174-9/S0025-5718-1964-0159174-9.pdf).

Comment: The formula $\frac x{\sqrt{\ln x}}$ implies that the numbers that has a sum of two perfect squares representation is sparser as $x$ increases, is this right?

Comment: Yep, the probability that a given number $k$ is representable is asymptotically $\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\ln k}}$.